# How to wait till Aerospike AsyncClient complete all transaction?

Tags: java, aerospike

I am using Aerospike AsyncClient and Aerospike UDF module to insert 10 Million record in Aerospike 2 node cluster using multiple thread. Steps that i follow are :

1. Created a executor service of 10 threads and all threads will use same AsyncClient
2. Run a loop 10 Million time and use below code to invoke execute command

   for(int 1-0; i < 10000000; i++) {
         final int j = i;
         executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
             put("test", "binname", "setname", j, list1, list2, aerospikeClient);
           }
         });
   }

> private void put(String namespace, String setName, String binName,
>   String keyVlaue,
>                     List campaignsIdsToBeAdd, List campaignsIdToBeRemoved, AsyncClient aerospikeClient) {
>                 Key key = new Key(namespace, setName, keyVlaue);
>                 aerospikeClient.execute(writePolicy, new WriteHandler(), key, "aerospike_udf", "update_record", Value.get(campaignsIdsToBeAdd),
>                         Value.get(campaignsIdToBeRemoved), Value.get(binName));
>             }

3. once executor exit i am calling close method

public void closed() {
        System.out.println("=== 1");

```
    if(aerospikeClient != null && aerospikeClient.isConnected())
        aerospikeClient.close();
    if(executorService != null && !executorService.isShutdown())
        executorService.shutdown();
}
```

4. executor service and AsyncClient stop immediately and after that there are no insertions happen and i am loosing submitted data.
5. Can any one help me to solve this? or suggest me the better way to use AsyncClient along with Aerospike udf function.
6. I tried to do this using sync client but it's took 70 min to insert all value but i want to complete it in 5 min. And when i tried to use Sync client between multiple thread it's throwing client timeout exception

Comment: to wait on a sequence of promises, try `Promise.sequence(promise1, promise2, ...)`

Answer (score 2):

Seems you are running udfs which are slower than regular read/write operations. So, even if you wait for the async calls to finish, you may end up taking more than 5 mins. You need to size the cluster to meet your performance needs. So, you need to look at non programming alternatives too.

- Having more nodes will help in executing the udfs in parallel, reducing the overall time.
- See the performance if you implement the logic of udf in the application. Sever will have less work as some computation cost is moved to the clients.

Comment: in udf i am doing get and then traverse on map of size at-most 10 and then update aerospike cluster contains 2 nodes with replica factor 2. I want similar feature like present in Thread executor where you can wait until all threads finished there execution or for some particular amount of time.

Comment: If you have only 2 nodes and cannot expand, try the non-udf route. Get the map and manipulate directly in your client and write it back. Use check-and-set(CAS) if you want to synchronise your writes across clients for same key.